# How to adjust or move the labels of arrows in tikz matrix of math nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I am trying to label crossing arrows in my tikz-matrix diagram. By default, the label is placed half-way of the path. Since the arrows cross half-way too, the labelling becomes ambiguous:

[image]

How can I 'move' the label downwards or upwards? Or is there a better environment for drawing this diagram?

Here is the tikz code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=4em,
    column sep=0.2em]{
    V& \quad \hookrightarrow \quad & H & \cong& H'& \quad \hookrightarrow &V' \\
    Q_+& \quad \hookrightarrow \quad & Q & \cong& Q '& \quad \hookrightarrow &Q_+' \\
    };
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge [densely dotted] node [left] {$J_1'$} (m-2-5) 
    (m-1-3) edge (m-2-7) 
    (m-2-1) edge  (m-1-5)
    (m-2-3) edge [densely dotted] (m-1-7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You're missing a semi-colon at the end of your `\path`. I suggest using `[xshift=-1.5em,yshift=.5em,left]` or something like that.

Comment: You can add the option `anchor=south` or `anchor=north` to the node options, so that it reads e.g. `[left, anchor=south]`

Comment: ok... I've just edited the code snippet

Comment: Oh, and maybe also add e.g. `pos=0.3`, which instructs TikZ to put the label at around 30% of the edge (instead of 50%, i.e., the midpoint). `anchor=north, pos=0.1` seems good to me. Add e.g. `xshift=2pt` or `yshift=2pt` for better positioning.

Comment: @Yori `pos` and `anchor` solved my question. Please, make a short answer out of it...

Comment: There are also two (generally) useful keys: `near start` and `near end`.

Comment: I also want to drop some useful keys: `auto` and `swap` (instead of `left`, `top`, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd like to present an answer using the beautiful package [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd).

**Update**

Here is a solution based on the version `v.0.3c`, the most recent.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} %some features in this code require v.0.3c 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzcd}
V \arrow[densely dotted, end anchor={[xshift=-3ex]north east}]{rd}[swap, pos=0.4, description]{J_1'} \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r} 
& H \cong H' \arrow[start anchor={[xshift=1.5ex]south west}, densely dotted]{rd}\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r} 
& V' \\

Q_+\arrow[densely dotted, end anchor={[xshift=-3ex]south east}]{ru}\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}
& Q \cong Q' \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}
& Q_+
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image: communewversion.png]

**Some Useful Anchors available** (the following image is a screenshot from [this](http://www.felixl.de/commu.pdf) tutorial that influenced the package `tikz-cd`):

### [image: anchorsareworthlearning.png]

> **Some preliminary remarks:** the newest version has a very clean interface to anchors (and I exploit anchors quite heavily in this solution). However, the old answer based on the version `v.0.3a` is here, in case you don't have access to the new version just like I did not have.

I highly recommend the following solution, which leaves no room for ambiguity about which arrow is being called J<sub>1</sub>'.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
V \arrow[densely dotted, end anchor=40]{rd}[swap, pos=0.77, description]{J_1'} \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r} 
& H \cong H' \arrow[start anchor=210, densely dotted]{rd}\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r} 
& V' \\

Q_+\arrow[densely dotted, end anchor=-60]{ru}\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}
& Q \cong Q' \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}
& Q_+
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

**The output:**

[image: commudes.png]

**Confusing-to-the-reader solution:**

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
V \arrow[densely dotted, end anchor=40]{rd}[swap, pos=0.65]{J_1'} \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r} 
& H \cong H' \arrow[start anchor=210, densely dotted]{rd}\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r} 
& V' \\

Q_+\arrow[densely dotted, end anchor=-60]{ru}\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}
& Q \cong Q' \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}
& Q_+
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image: commu.png]

Comment: Thank you for this thorough introduction into tikz-cd... I will just shrink the hooked arrows, as they are mathematical relations rather than arrows.

Comment: @Jan Glad to have been of help. Sure, do as you please! :)